# Serial upvote rep not reversed on reputation graph

Tags: support, serial-voting, reputation-recalc

A [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3164770/user3164770?tab=reputation) for whom I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225730/having-trouble-drawing-google-piechart-using-data-from-mysql-database/22229501#22229501) (I just looked at their profile for curiosity) earned 135 rep on 1 March 2014 from serial upvoting, which was reversed the day after. OK.

According to [this accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/197939), a reversal triggers a reputation recalculation.

My question is, why does the user still seem to have gained that 135 rep on the Reputation graph?

> [image: inaccurate graph]

It should be zero. Are the graphs static and not included in the reputation recalculation? 
If not, I think they should be - if it is possible, of course.

Comment: It's +135 on one day and -135 on the next. If it just "disappeared" it wouldn't be clear exactly what happened to it

Comment: Yes, that is what I do not understand. If the upvotes are resetted, then the graph also should be ..?

Comment: The events aren't reset (note you can still see then in the rep history). A new reversal event is generated;  the two events together are a net zero (it gets more complicated when repcaps are involved but that's the gist)

Comment: Yes, but the graph should be updated also, in my opinion. I was actually surprised it is not being updated.

Comment: See Robert Harvey answer. That looks exactly how I would expect it to look

Comment: It is the Indian approach, meant to make them think it worked.

Comment: david, the graph is not showing cumulative reputation, it is showing the reputation by day. That user **did** gain +135 reputation on that day. When the serial upvoting was discovered, they did not lose that +135 reputation, they received a separate adjustment of -135 reputation to eliminate the gain from the serial upvoting. While +135 and -135 will result in a net change of zero in reputation, the graph is not showing net change, but rather than changes by day. If I get 1 upvote on an answer today (+10 rep), and 5 downvotes on it tomorrow (-10 rep), it will still show +10 yesterday -10 today

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Days during which a user loses more reputation than they gain are shown as zero reputation on the graph on the [user summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3164770/user3164770?tab=summary). You can even see this on [your own profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/197939/davidkonrad).

As you can see on the [detailed reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3164770/user3164770?tab=reputation), the serial upvoting occurred on march first, but the reversal didn't occur until march second at 3:00:

> [image]

So the user gained reputation on Mar 1, which is clearly shown on the graph on the summary page. The user also lost all that reputation the *next* day, so the lost reputation *would* be shown on the next bar of the graph, *if* negative reputation were shown on the summary page graph. If you hover over that bar, you will see that even though there is no red bar pointing down, there is still a rep loss on that day:

> [image]

Comment: Yeah, I can see that - this is my question in short.

Comment: @davidkonrad: Nothing follows.  The reputation was earned yesterday, but revoked today.

Comment: Yes, but the graph should show rep actually earned, also retrospectiveliy.

Answer (score 14):

The graph on the user's Summary page is meant to show a pattern of activity... *how active the user is on the site over a period of time.*  It is similar to this graph (volume of Google stock shares traded):

[image]

Note that we have no interest in the *direction* that shares were traded, but merely how many shares changed hands. The graph itself is by no means accurate, but merely shows a visual trend.

If you want an *accurate* graph, you have to go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3164770/user3164770?tab=reputation&sort=graph):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, but this is not how normal (under 10000 rep I guess) users see the graph. They see the graph i posted in the question.

Comment: I took this picture from a 1 rep account.  If I'm seeing something that you're not seeing, it would be highly unusual.  Did you look here? http://stackoverflow.com/users/3164770/user3164770?tab=reputation

Comment: @davidKonrad this is also how the graph looks to me

Comment: @davidkonrad There are two different graphs, one on the summary page and one on the reputation page.

Comment: @Robert, have never seen such a reputation graph.

Comment: Did you look here? http://stackoverflow.com/users/3164770/user3164770?tab=reputation

Comment: @davidkonrad Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3164770/user3164770?tab=reputation&sort=graph

Comment: It is the summary page I have in focus. It is still wrong, regardless anything else.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `?tab=reputation` doesn't link directly to the graph; `?tab=reputation&sort=graph` does.

Comment: Alright, I finally see it.  Is that really a problem, or does it just bother you that they didn't put in the negative red bars?  Especially when there isn't even a scale on that graph, and they've given you a page that provides a detailed report?

Comment: @David A bank robber stole 1 million from a bank on tuesday, on friday they were arrested and the money returned to the bank; plot the bank robber's net worth over time. The existing graph on the detailed page is correct

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, that doesnt help on the summary page reputation graph, does it? Try read my question again, everybody. I talk about the reputation graph on the summary page, not everything else.

Comment: @RichardTingle: He's looking at the user's summary page.

Comment: @Robert I took "regardless" to mean "both are wrong"

Comment: OK, so tomorrow the reputation graph for that user will show 0 points?

Comment: @davidkonrad No.

Comment: @davidkonrad: I think the answer is that, if you're looking for that level of detail, you're looking in the wrong place.  If I were tasked with this, my recommendation would be just to remove it, rather than try to fix it.

Comment: Note, I am not after this user. It just seemed strange.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat. _"no"_. OK, then I suggest the reputation graph should be "recalculated" along with the rep score.

Comment: @davidkonrad There is no recalculation necessary. I'm editing my answer to explain this more clearly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, So I am "right", the graph on the summary page is not updated under rep recalculation? OK if that is the answer. I suggest it should be updated, but of course I do not know the effort to accomplish that nor the impact on the servers.

Comment: @davidkonrad No, the graph is probably still updated upon rep recalculation. That is irrelevant, though; see my answer.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, But should it not be accurate? Anyway. I accept your answer, but have in mind that most likely other people but me will be baffled over this in the future. SO is so great constructed that one assumes everything is thinked of. And if not, one think it must be some kind of failure.